# Load GeoJSON into layer from a URL?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox 2.1 and I'm trying to build a chloropleth map from a GeoJSON source, working from this example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/choropleth/

However, I've fallen at the first hurdle, because my GeoJSON source is a pure GeoJSON file, not a JS file like their example.

So this line doesn't work for me:

```
var statesLayer = L.geoJson(statesData,  {
    style: getStyle,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Their [JS file](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/assets/data/us-states.js) defines `statesData` as a variable:

```
var statesData = { "type": "FeatureCollection" ... };
```

But my GeoJSON file is just a GeoJSON file.

How can I define the equivalent of `statesData` so that I can follow the example?

I guess I could use `eval` to read in the GeoJSON, but that's generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax to snag the data from your own site

Here is a jquery way of doing it.

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "json", //you shouldn't need to declare geojson
url: "data/district.geojson",
success: function(data) {
    //whatever you want to do with the data, alternatively you could use a closer around the ajax request to capture the data into a variable depending on how you have your code organized
}
}).error(function(e) {
     console.log(e)
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing.