# Load Remote GeoJSON from URL Synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to load a remote/external GeoJSON file containing a `FeatureCollection` from a URL using JavaScript, then select only some of the features to ultimately load to a Leaflet map. I'd think this should be simple, but clearly not...

Methods I've tried:

1. Using [`leaflet-omnivore`](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) to load the GeoJSON file to a GeoJSON
   object. This seemed to load the file improperly, such that I got
   `Invalid GeoJSON object` errors.
2. Using jQuery + AJAX to load the GeoJSON file as a JSON object as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30809081/9910708); this seemed to work as far as loading the file
   goes, but then I get `[variable] is not defined` errors when I try
   to interact with the JSON object later. I assume this is due to the
   asynchronous nature of AJAX?
3. Using jQuery + getJSON to load the GeoJSON file as a JSON object as detailed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/113353/151149); I ran into the same problems as with AJAX
   above.

How can I load this GeoJSON file in such a way I can continue to manipulate it as an object?

---

Here's my JavaScript showing case (3):

```js
// Define URL path to geojson file containing FeatureCollection
var url = "https://blah.blah.geojson";

// Load geojson file as JSON object
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        // Turn JSON object into geojson object
        var geoJson_data = L.geoJson(data);
    });

// Create list of properties to filter by
var list_of_props = ['foo', 'bar', 'boop'];

// Define restriction to certain features
var data_filtered = L.geoJson(geoJson_data, {  // <- "geoJson_data is not defined" error occurs here
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties) {
            return feature.properties.foo in list_of_props;
        }
    }
});

// Ultimately I'd want to add the filtered data to a map like so...
data_filtered.add_To(previouslyDefinedLeafletMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

For all methods using an Ajax call (like getJSON) you have to process the data in the callback method.

The best way to write your code would be ...

```
// Load geojson file as JSON object
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    processJSON(data);
});  

function processJSON(data) {
    // Turn JSON object into geojson object
    var geoJson_data = L.geoJson(data);

   // Define restriction to certain features
   var data_filtered = L.geoJson(geoJson_data, { 
     filter: function(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties) {
          return feature.properties.foo in list_of_props;
        }
     }    
 });

   // Ultimately I'd want to add the filtered data to a map like so...
   data_filtered.add_To(previouslyDefinedLeafletMap);
}
```

Comment: I think I'm going to end up doing something like this. I'm just surprised there isn't a non-Ajax option for downloading and processing a file!